# Calibre ebook-convert command not found

Tags: ruby, rake, calibre

I'm working through Avdi Grimm's tutorial series on Rake, and I'm stuck on [Part 6](http://devblog.avdi.org/2014/04/28/rake-part-6-clean-and-clobber/). The tasks that invoke Pandoc work fine, but Calibre's `ebook-convert` command returns a Status 127:

```
andrekibbe@Andres-MacBook rake_basics (master) $ rake
pandoc -o ch1.html ch1.md
pandoc -o ch2.html ch2.md
pandoc -o ch3.html ch3.md
pandoc -o subdir/appendix.html subdir/appendix.md
pandoc -o ch4.html ch4.markdown
cat ch1.html ch2.html ch3.html ch4.html  > book.html
ebook-convert book.html book.epub
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (127): [ebook-convert book.html book.epub...]
/Users/andrekibbe/code/rake_basics/Rakefile:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/andrekibbe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/andrekibbe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => default => book.epub
```

`ebook-convert` is in a path of my Applications directory: `/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/calibre`, while my Rakefile is in `/Users/andrekibbe/code/rake_basics`:

```
require "rake/clean"

SOURCE_FILES = Rake::FileList.new("**/*.md", "**/*.markdown") do |fl|
  fl.exclude("~*")
  fl.exclude(/^scratch\//)
  fl.exclude do |f|
    `git ls-files #{f}`.empty?
  end
end
CLEAN.include(SOURCE_FILES.ext(".html"))

task default: ["book.epub", "book.mobi"]
task html: SOURCE_FILES.ext(".html")

rule ".html" => ->(f){source_for_html(f)} do |t|
  sh "pandoc -o #{t.name} #{t.source}"
end

file "book.html" => SOURCE_FILES.ext(".html") do |t|
  chapters   = FileList["**/ch*.html"]
  backmatter = FileList["backmatter/*.html"]
  sh "cat #{chapters} #{backmatter} > #{t.name}"
end
CLEAN.include("book.html")

file "book.epub" => "book.html" do |t|
  sh "ebook-convert book.html #{t.name}"
end
CLOBBER.include("book.epub")

file "book.mobi" => "book.epub" do |t|
  sh "kindlegen book.epub -o #{t.name}"
end
CLOBBER.include("book.mobi")

def source_for_html(html_file)
  SOURCE_FILES.detect{|f| f.ext('') == html_file.ext('')}
end
```

Is there a way to require the Calibre tools in the Rakefile, like a gem, or use the absolute path or a symlink? I don't think it should be necessary, since there's nothing like that in Avdi's code. Or do I need to install Calibre elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 127 is "command not found".  http://otaku-elite.com/blog/2013/06/06/rake-status-127/

As a first step, you might try **which ebook-convert** and then use the full path.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `ebook-convert` is not in path. You should use full path of `ebook-convert` or add it to path.

Change your

```sh
ebook-convert book.html book.epub
```

To

```sh
/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert book.html book.epub
```

Or add `ln` to /usr/local/bin and try again

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert /usr/local/bin
```